# Error on calling a c++ function from python

Tags: opencv, image-processing, boost-python

I'm new in Python and I want to call a c++ function inside a python module. after reading about ctype, cython, swig, etc, I decided to use boost: python to call two simple c++ function.

I wrote this c++ function:

```
const char* hi()
{
        return "hello world!";
}

Mat read_image()
{
        Mat s = imread("logo.png");

       /*
        *    Some preprocessing on image
        *
        */

        return (s.data);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
        def("hi", hi);
        def("read_image", read_image);
}
```

and this is my python's code:

```
import hello
import cv2
import numpy as np


print(hello.hi())

new_image = hello.read_image()
```

The first function (hi), works correctly, but for the second function which wants to do some preprocessing on the image, it doesn't work and shows this error:

new_image = hello.read_image()
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: cv::Mat

can anyone help me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You need to write code to convert the `cv::Mat` object to a Python object. Boost doesn’t know about OpenCV’s classes.

Comment: @crisluengo How can write this convertor? is it using in memory in order to convert?
because performance is very important to me.

Comment: There is no need to copy the data, but you need to create a Python object that encapsulates this data. There are tutorials out there for how to do this. I would recommend that you use [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) instead of Boost.Python (it's derived from it, and progressed way beyond it; it's much much better). In short, you create an interface for `cv::Mat`, and expose its buffer. Within Python you will then be able to use this object in the same way you use any NumPy array. See here: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#buffer-protocol

Comment: @CrisLuengo Given that OP needs a numpy array and that boost::python already includes numpy bindings, that might be the easiest choice, as opposed to changing the binding library...

Comment: Also the problem is already solved in OpenCV Python bindings, so that might be a useful thing to consult as well. -- [here](https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter) is that part extracted into standalone code.  IIRC it works quite fine, I use it in a few apps.

Comment: @Dan: pybind11 is just a huge improvement over Boost::Python. It's not changing the binding library, it's taking a step out of the past into the present. Pybind11 also has NumPy bindings, but it's an effort to output a NumPy array, it's easier to create an interface around your C++ class and offer a buffer protocol.

Comment: For example: [here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/bc27fccbf4abb3755f37d7c1fa679e23579f7c85/pydip/src/image.cpp#L221) I create an interface around a custom image class, and [here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/bc27fccbf4abb3755f37d7c1fa679e23579f7c85/pydip/src/image.cpp#L122) is the function to write to expose the buffer protocol.

Comment: @Dan: That library looks pretty convenient too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Interesting. So far BP did what I needed, so I took a "Don't fix it if it ain't broke" approach (more so given that I already have boost around anyway as opposed to pulling in another library. I'll have to add it to the "to research" pile. Cheers.